# VSCode doesn't highlight extra spaces as errors

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use "Prettier" extension.
Here should be highlighted errors:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Alex can you please try closing vs code completely and restart it. For me this happens due to heavy usage of vs code or cause of long term usage. Please let me know if it helps. Prettier works perfectly after it

Comment: Hey Alex. Prettier is a formatter, not a linter, so it can't show warnings or errors. Try installing ESLint and installing the VS Code ESLint extension to show those errors and warnings. Don't forget to configure your ESLint with Prettier-compatible rules.